# Time series: Why is this MA(1) process invertible?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I'm trying to understanding the concept of invertibility in time series using the following example.

Consider the process $X_t = Z_t + \frac{1}{2}Z_{t-1}$, where $\{Z_t\}$ is a pure noise process with mean 0 and variance $\sigma_z^2$.

According to my text, this process is invertible since $f(x) = 1+\frac{1}{2}x$ has a single root, $x=-2$, which lies outside the unit circle.

So why is the process invertible? I think the reasoning is something like this: we can recursively solve for $Z_t:$
$$\begin{align*}
Z_t &= X_t - \frac{1}{2}Z_{t-1} \\&= X_t-\frac{1}{2}(X_{t-1}-\frac{1}{2}Z_{t-2}) \\&= \cdots \\&= X_t - \frac{1}{2}X_{t-1} + \frac{1}{2^2}X_{t-2} - \frac{1}{2^3}X_{t-3} - \cdots \end{align*}$$

I see that the coefficients above are going to $0$, but how does this allow us to actually invert the process? What is the relationship between this observation and the fact that $f(x)$ above has all its roots outside the unit circle?

Comment: The series $Z_t=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a^nX_{t-n}$ with $a=-\frac12$ converges because $|a|<1$. Since $a$ is the inverse of the root of the polynomial $f(x)$, indeed, the roots of $f(x)$ not being in the unit disk is the key.

Comment: This is an $\mathrm{AR}(1)$ process; a $\mathrm{MA}(1)$ process would be of the form
$$
X_t = Z_t + \frac12 Z_{t-1}.
$$
Moreover, finite-order AR processes are always invertible - did you mean to ask about stationarity, or about a MA process?

Comment: I meant to ask about the MA process as you wrote it. I originally had a typo, which is fixed now.